# Mass install linux by dd to drive directly?

Tags: system-installation, dd, secure-boot

I need to install an custom OS to many similar/identical laptops. Would it work to live boot a laptop and dd the disk from a template laptop to the new one? Is it possible to trigger secure boot key enrolment afterwards?

Comment: Note that dd will copy everything including blank sectors. So if install is 20GB on a 1TB drive, your dd will copy 1TB. And will not install the UEFI boot entry into UEFI. You only need MOK if you have proprietary driver that you have to authorize. I do a full desktop install from RAM (toram parameter) to SSD in 10 min. Run scripts to customize install and download list of installed apps. Another alternative: debootstrap: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2496327&p=14183449#post14183449 If you have good backup, just do new install & restore backup.

Comment: An alternative with Ubuntu is to use [OEM installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), but that method is not generally available in all Linux distros. -- You make a master system and clone that master system to other targets (drives/computers). [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) is more efficient than dd because it copies only used block (which contain data belonging to files).